# Matlab write cell array of numbers into file

Tags: matlab, cell-array, writetofile

I have a cell array like this:

```
cellarr{1}=[1 2 3];
cellarr{2}=[1 2 3 4 5 6];
...
```

Each cell is a vector of numbers with different length. I want to write this cell array into a text file so that i can read it later. The text file should look like this:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

If I use `dlmwrite('file.txt',cellarr,'\t')` it puts all cells into one line. How do I put a new line character after writing a cell to the text file?

P/S: I could use fprintf with two `for` loops to get what I want. But is there a faster way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was wondering why do you need two for loops?

```
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'wt');
for i = 1 : length(cellarr)
   fprintf(fid, '%d\t', cellarr{i});
   fprintf(fid,'\n');
end
fclose(fid)
```

Comment: This writes everything in one line

Comment: great, the 'wt' saves me from adding one for loop